# что эта за ерунда на странице AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

есть страница на которой форма генерится джангой.

форму выдает, но на странице еще строка

```
(u'QmFyRm9ybQ', u'djng-form-errors', u'$pristine', u'$error.rejected', u'invalid', u'$message')
```

и еще по одной у каждого поля формы.

что это ошибка или что?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Без рабочего примера нельзя сказать наверняка. Это может быть как нормальное поведение соответствующее разметке, так и ошибки в коде генерилки или контроллера/компоненты ангуляра

Comment: я так понял это выводит crispy-forms

Comment: Без понятия, что это такое. Повторюсь, без примера - можно только гадать